# Is there any BigEndian hardware out there?

Tags: endianness

I consider throwing out code that handles the big endian case from a library and instead simply throw an expception during initialization if the platform is not little endian. I cannot imagine that there is any big endian hardware if we restrict to

- typical server hardware for any web site hosted
- servers according to the open compute project spec
- all common mobile devices

Did anybody lately encounter a Big Endian machine or device that does not belong to the dinnosaur park?

Comment: Solaris on Sparc, AIX on Power

Comment: I thought Sun softly migrated to Intel with the aquisition of Kealia in 2003 or so? AIX/6000 was lastly produced 2010 according to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIX#Power.2C_PowerPC . thx I feel safe not meeting those 2.

Comment: Oracle and Fujistu still manufacture and sell Sparc hardware (search for Oracle SuperCluster or T5 for current hardware). AIX is still alive and kicking, but on Power, not PowerPC. Search for IBM Power E880, or just Power8 to get the wiki for the latest chip in that line. (It's bi-endian, but AIX runs in big endian configuration.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows only supports little-endian processors ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/07/426334.aspx ) however it seems all of the platforms that matter (so-to-speak) are either little-endian already (x86, AMD64) or support little-endian mode (ARM, [POWER/PowerPC](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/fe313521-2e95-46f2-817d-44a4f27eba32/entry/just_the_faqs_about_little_endian?lang=en), Itanium, etc).

While there are exclusively big-endian hardware platforms, they're increasingly rare and obscure - however if the cost of maintaining BE/LE-compatible code isn't too much trouble then I think it's worthwhile to keep it: I assume that it's only a matter of performing conversion in the entrypoints and output calls of your code, internally you shouldn't need to do anything.